# Preventing RestKit mapping from auto save

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, mapping, restkit

I'm using RestKit to map an XML file. In that file are several items that map to a class, let's call it `ListItem`. These listitems have a reference to a thumbnail image file. As soon as the mapping is done I'm starting the download of the thumbnails so I can be sure they are available when I need them.

Now I'd like to make sure these files are downloaded properly. Checking for the existance of the files in the cache won't be a problem, but I'd like the context only to be saved when the download of all files was successful.

I just can't figure out at which point the saving is being done. After I call the mapping method

```
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"data.xml" delegate:self];
```

the mapping is being done and I get the result in

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects
```

This is the point where I start the image download, but at that point the context has already been saved. I don't know how to prevent this behavior.

The only idea I came up with is duplicating the sql file and using the duplicate-file for the `objectStore` to perform the sync. When the sync is successful overriding the original sql with the duplicate.

Does anybody know a better way to do this? Did I miss a method that is being called in the mapping process?